# Is it possible to send a large video file (larger than 4 Gig) from browser via a webrtc or other and stream it via HLS or other format?

Tags: html, video-streaming, webrtc, chunks, chunked-encoding

My question is for HTML side of things (via a broswer like chrome or safari)...

**** also the main concern is chrome / safari limitation when sending file over 4 Gig via a
`<input type="file" >`

Example : https://obsproject.com/ is a streaming software that you install on a desktop to stream a from a camera or from a video file to RTMP endpoint....

but is it doable to to the same (send a pre-recorded .mov) and stream it to a server and that server to "record" it to make it available after the stream... like using webrtc api of the browser and send it to a multipoint control unit (MCU) and record or convert to HLS .m3u8 format...

digging in google made me found this
https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/capture/video-pc/
the the demo don't work :(

••••• I found this too https://github.com/muaz-khan/FileBufferReader with `function FileBufferReader() {...`

but what about recording (from the user browser to an other peer, but that other peer could be a server that takes this "stream" and re-assemble it and do a .m3u8 HLS format) ?

Comment: I haven't heard of a 4 GB limit for file input.  Do you have a link or some reference for that?

Comment: @Brad https://www.motobit.com/help/scptutl/pa98.htm

Comment: @Brad I also experienced it myself, I Increased server side max 11 Gig, when It sent a 5 gig file the console output some weird error `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING`

Answer (score 0):

Delivering a 4 GB file is problematic- any network hiccup during delivery could cause an issue.

OBS sends a video RTMP stream to many services to "live stream" like Twitch, YouTube, etc (I work for [api.video](https://api.video), and we sponsor OBS, and can be used to livestream this way).

These services convert the RTMP stream into HLS for you and deliver the streams to your customers.

If you have a 4 GB .mov file - you can upload that to services as well to convert to the HLS format.  But - like you said, 4Gb can be problematic.  Our workaround has been to use file.slice in JavaSCript to split the big video in to manageable chunks (that are reassembled on the server).

I've written a blog post on how to do this:
https://api.video/blog/tutorials/uploading-large-files-with-javascript

and a live demo (using the api.video backend): https://upload.a.video

Doug